# Can one assign different priorities to Handlers or Messages being processed by Looper?

Tags: android, android-looper

I am aware that the recommended way of doing background-like tasks in Android is to start a worker thread of some kind, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler alternative available when the background tasks are small and numerous. So here's my question:

When creating a new Handler for the UI thread Looper, can it somehow be given a lower priority than the default Handler that runs the UI? Or alternatively, when queuing Messages to be processed by the Handler/Looper, can individual Messages be given lower priority than the default Messages, so they get queued behind the UI Messages, and new UI Messages will get queued in front of them?

I'm just thinking that if this is possible it would be good enough for my app, and I could avoid the extra coding needed to have a worker thread and to interface the UI and worker threads.

Comment: Did you ever figure that out?